# Why can't markdown used by Stack Exchange properly render a backward slash?

Tags: support, markdown

If I type it in between these parentheses -> () the backward slash inside the parentheses is removed.  As you see it is not there.  However if I surround it with spaces ( \ ), then it is rendered correctly.

Comment: If you think that's bad, try reproducing this comment: `\​`.

Comment: I meant a backslash in a `code block` (surrounded by `\``s).

Comment: (I know that other post is about chat, but it's a general "[things the backslash escapes in Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash)" problem)

Comment: *I've given up* trying to reproduce the comment: `\\`

Comment: If you think that's bad, try reproducing this comment: `\‍‍‍`.

Comment: If you think that's bad, try not asking questions about fight club at fight club.  Ask them on meta fight club.

Comment: Reopened, chat is using a different markdown.

Answer (score 18):

What happens is that the backslash is interpreted as an escape character for the `)` parenthesis (as it's used in Markdown for things like links).

If you want to type a literal backslash without using backticks for `code`, double it instead.

`(\\)` → (\)