# How can I escape the less than symbol when it is next to a alphabetical character?

Tags: support, markdown

I was pasting results from Google Translate into a quote in a question and it looked like this

> By overlaying the more because

In reality the markdown is this

```
>By overlaying the more because <What is the other side 
` Ru to one representing the thumb of muscle 
< To SenWataru and ho stick base of Ne亢layers of trout 
Although a state of twisted without breaking the non- g was Li 
Only to cowpea in the following figure around the hand of Saki珊 
Become good long as )
```

This is not related to blockquoting since it does not matter that I am doing that. I know the issue is the less than symbol because it is immediately next to the alphabetical character W. I am assuming the renderer is seeing a partial html tag. If I put a number there or a space instead it is fine.

Likely this is a dupe but I didn't find what I was looking for outside of the following:

[Why can't markdown used by Stack Exchange properly render a backward slash?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122910/why-cant-markdown-used-by-stack-exchange-properly-render-a-backward-slash)

Which does not help since I am not working with backslashes.

Comment: I answered my own question while trying to be sure there wasnt a dupe. There still could be.... The sandbox is not a good dupe target so I pulled out what I wanted to so I had an answer.

Comment: Cheers, this got nothing to do with the less than character being next to alphabetical character, and also not related to being inside a blockquote.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for finding the dupe. I know the blockquote is not related. I mentioned that in the question. What is the actual problem then? I only said alpha since a number, for example, didn't cause the same issue.

Comment: The "problem" (which isn't a problem, see in a bit) is that for security reasons, SE strips all possible HTML tags, except those which are whitelisted, e.g. `<a>`, `<img>` etc. So the combination of `<` followed by a letter is considered a possible tag and stripped, unless formatted as code. I might have been wrong to say "nothing to do with the less than character being next to alphabetical character" - it's just not the way you thought it is. So, since HTML tags must begin with English letter, it won't strip when the `<` is followed by digit, or non English character. Hope it's clear now! :)

Comment: Yes its clear. My fault for saying alphabetical and being ignorant of the greater character set. I only usually think of standard ansi code when I saw alphabetical. I was close to right but my reasoning was not completely correct.

Comment: Yup. All good, and keep in mind you can also use the backtick to format the less than symbol, though unlike using `&lt;` it will get a different format and color.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to avoid code markup.

Answer (score 29):

I found an answer in the Formatting Sandbox from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270181/266361)

> `&lt;derp>`

So using the HTML entity for less than `&lt` does the job.

Comment: Its &lt; Do not miss the ending semi colon character.

Comment: It also works for `&gt;`. :)